# Why is this sed RegEx expression chopping off digits in certain circumstances?

Tags: regex, macos, sed, itunes

```
sed -e 's/ *-\{0,1\},\{0,1\} *[Pp][Aa]\{0,1\}[Rr]\{0,1\}[Tt].\{0,1\} *\([0-9]\{1,\}\) *$/ (\1)/'
```

I'm piping titles through this from an iTunes AppleScript. This should convert any title with a Part designation at the end to a parenthetical format

For instance, `Best of Both Worlds, Part 2` becomes `Best of Both Worlds (2)`.

The trouble rears its head when a space is omitted between `Part` and the digit(s).

- If it's a single digit, it works fine. `Blah part2` becomes `Blah (2)`
- More than one digit, and the first digit gets cut off: `Blah pt123` becomes `Blah (23)`

I freely admit that I'm no RegEx expert, but I dug around both in the book "Mastering Regular Expressions" and searched google without luck. Any idea what's going awry here? Thanks!

Comment: You can replace each `\{0,1\}` with `\?` and `\{1,\}` with `\+` (`\{0,\} is equivalent to `*`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The '`.\{0,1\}`' matches the 1.

Replace the `.` with `[^0-9]`.

Comment: Oh! Duh. Except I actually do only want to match a period, so I should replace the `.` with `[.]`. Thanks for the kick in the head!

Comment: @bobtiki: Instead of `[.]` you can use `\.`